# Lufthansa 48 hour reservation with Price Guarantee

Tags: fees-and-charges, lufthansa

I used the Lufthansa 48 hour reservation with Price Guarantee option on the Lufthansa website yesterday.  I then decided to go ahead with the booking and completed and paid for the flight on the same site.  However, my credit card appears to have been charged the £27 for the reservation as well at the cost of the flight.  Is this normal, or should the £27 only have been deducted if I didn't book within 48 hours?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you confirmed the reservation through the My Bookings page, and haven't made a completely new booking, you don't have to pay the reservation fee.

More likely the credit card transaction, that you see is only a hold and not an actual deduction. The hold should disappear in a couple of days. If not, then you can dispute that transaction with the reference to the conditions of the reservation guarantee.

Comment: looking at my credit card account, both the £27 and the cost of the flight are showing as "pending".  I will wait a couple of says to see if the £27 disappears.

Comment: @kate: As long as it doesn't move from "pending" to "charged", it is routine for those credit-card holds to linger on for up to about a month after they're made. If it doesn't get _charged_ within that month, it will disappear from your statement by itself, and you're not out any money.